# Any listener for system preferences in Android

Tags: android, preferences

I want to capture event when an user try to go into the preferences screen, so I can ask password for it. The reason why I try this, I am developing app for the disabled. I don't want them to touch system settings directly, just the permitted helper.

Is there any event listener or receiver for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything in the public APIs that will allow you to do this. [Device Admin](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html) is probably the closest thing, but I don't think it does this exactly.

If you wish to implement this (and be certain that it will be effective) you'd have to modify the OS slightly on your devices.

One possibility that *might* work and is within the APIs is to create a replacement home screen that does not show the usual items in the menu. If you were to go this route you could "lock" the into your activity and simply provide them no way to go to the settings except with a password or something. This would be a lot of work though, and would require the user to set your application as their default home screen. And even with this on the newer devices you may run into the trouble because there is a settings button inside the notification pull down, which I don't think there is a way to block, even with a replacement homescreen.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It sounds tough, I will try.